# Python string concatenation taking different time in linux and windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried running string concatenation on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu on Python 3.6. 
The time taken in Ubuntu is 2-3 second while in Windows it take  very long time. Both Windows and Ubuntu are on same machine.

```
content=''
for i in range(10000000):
    content+='SomeString'
```

Why is it the case ?

Comment: You should precise your question which seems to be. `Why is it the case ?`

Comment: Surely a better question is: why are you repeatedly concatenating strings? Use `''.join('SomeString' for _ in range(10000000))`, then you don't create 9,999,999 redundant intermediate strings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would definetly use this. But I just want to know the reason Why its different on Linux and Windows

Comment: Because Ubuntu and Windows are different OS (and with different kind of kernels). Isn't that reason enough?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. You are putting one string in a memory location and assigning it to variable. Then you are concatenating its copy  to another string, putting it in some other memory location and making variable content point to new memory location. This act of continuous new memory space allocation for the string is taking time in a loop.

Comment: Why this is not the case in Linux

Comment: But that's not the answer for why Windows and Ubuntu are taking different time

Comment: Ubuntu is doing better memory allocation and management for the scenario. What are your compilers in ubuntu and windows?